# How to enter barcode manually to fetch the data in react-native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, barcode, react-native-camera

I'm using [react-native-camera](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera) to scan the barcode of type `code128` only which is working fine.

Now, the app scans the barcode and on successful scanning navigates to a new page displaying the type of barcode and the details from the barcode.

**I also want to type the barcode number manually in a textinput and do the same in case scanning fails. How do I do that ?**

Comment: That's why `onRead` callback is there for you, if scanning fails it return null. On the basis of that you can show TextInput, so user can input data and you can perform task based on data.

Comment: You mean the onBarcodeRead() right?. That I understand. How do the checking works when I enter a barcode number? When scanning , I'm displaying the data returned by onBarcodeRead() but in the case of manually entering what to do?

Comment: On barcode read, your app perform action on the basis of that data right?